# ERRO: Call to undefined function VerificaCPF()!

Tags: php, javascript, debug

Olá meu código está dando erro na hora de verificar se o resultado de uma função é TRUE, segue o código abaixo:

```html
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Conecxão Falhou: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
 
 echo "Conexao foi um sucesso";
 
if(VerificaCPF($cpf) === TRUE){
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO pessoas VALUES ("'.$nome.'", "'.$cpf.'", "'.$cep.'" , "'.$rua.'", "'.$bairro.'", "'.$cidade.'", "'.$uf.'", "'.$ibge.'")';
 //verificando se os valores foram inseridos//
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "<br>Os valores foram adicionados corretamente";
 } else {
  echo "<br>Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   
 }
}else{
 echo "Os valores nham foram";
}

?>
```

```html
function VerificaCPF($cpf) {
  if (vercpf(document.frmcpf.cpf.value)) 
    {document.frmcpf.submit();}else 
      {errors="1";if (errors) alert('CPF NÃO VÁLIDO');
  document.retorno = (errors == '');}}
function vercpf (cpf) 
  {if (cpf.length != 11 || cpf == "000.000.000-00" || cpf == "11111111111" || cpf     == "22222222222" || cpf == "33333333333" || cpf == "44444444444" || cpf ==         "55555555555" || cpf == "66666666666" || cpf == "77777777777" || cpf ==           "88888888888" || cpf == "99999999999")
  return false;
 add = 0;
for (i=0; i < 9; i ++)
  add += parseInt(cpf.charAt(i)) * (10 - i);
  rev = 11 - (add % 11);
if (rev == 10 || rev == 11)
  rev = 0;
if (rev != parseInt(cpf.charAt(9)))
  return false;
  add = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
  add += parseInt(cpf.charAt(i)) * (11 - i);
  rev = 11 - (add % 11);
if (rev == 10 || rev == 11)
  rev = 0;
if (rev != parseInt(cpf.charAt(10)))
  return false;
alert('O CPF INFORMADO É VÁLIDO.');
  return true;}
```

Comment: Essa função não é reconhecida pelo php pq foi definida no javascript logo ... lembre que o javascript trabalha no lado cliente e o php no servidor.

Comment: então eu teria de fazer a verificação do resultado por java, ou utilizar um código em php?

Comment: Se a função VerificaCPF foi criada no javascript, você só poderá utilizá-la lá

Comment: Se você quer utilizá-la no PHP, deverá criá-la no PHP

Comment: okay Obrigado pela ajuda vou finalizar por aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Eae galera segue abaixo a resposta, agradeço desde já ao @rray e o @Julyano Felipe que me ajudaram pelos comentários, foi um erro meu que foi resolvido graças as criticas construtivas deles Obrigado.

```html
<?php
function validaCPF($cpf = null) {

 // Verifica se um número foi informado
 if(empty($cpf)) {
  return false;
 }

 // Elimina possivel mascara
 $cpf = ereg_replace('[^0-9]', '', $cpf);
 $cpf = str_pad($cpf, 11, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  
 // Verifica se o numero de digitos informados é igual a 11
 if (strlen($cpf) != 11) {
  return false;
 }
 // Verifica se nenhuma das sequências invalidas abaixo
 // foi digitada. Caso afirmativo, retorna falso
 else if ($cpf == '00000000000' ||
   $cpf == '11111111111' ||
   $cpf == '22222222222' ||
   $cpf == '33333333333' ||
   $cpf == '44444444444' ||
   $cpf == '55555555555' ||
   $cpf == '66666666666' ||
   $cpf == '77777777777' ||
   $cpf == '88888888888' ||
   $cpf == '99999999999') {
    return false;
    // Calcula os digitos verificadores para verificar se o
    // CPF é válido
   } else {
     
    for ($t = 9; $t < 11; $t++) {
      
     for ($d = 0, $c = 0; $c < $t; $c++) {
      $d += $cpf{$c} * (($t + 1) - $c);
     }
     $d = ((10 * $d) % 11) % 10;
     if ($cpf{$c} != $d) {
      return false;
     }
    }

    return true;
   }
}

//declarando variaveis//
 $servername = 'localhost';
 $username = 'root';
 $password = '';
 $dbname = 'meubd';
 $nome = $_POST['nom'];
 $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
 $cep = $_POST['end'];
 $rua = $_POST['rua'];
 $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
 $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
 $uf = $_POST['uf'];
 $ibge = $_POST['ibge'];
 
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Conecxão Falhou: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
 
 echo "Conexao foi um sucesso";
 
if(validaCPF($cpf) === TRUE){
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO pessoas VALUES ("'.$nome.'", "'.$cpf.'", "'.$cep.'" , "'.$rua.'", "'.$bairro.'", "'.$cidade.'", "'.$uf.'", "'.$ibge.'")';
 //verificando se os valores foram inseridos//
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "<br>Os valores foram adicionados corretamente";
 } else {
  echo "<br>Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   
 }
}else{
 echo "Os valores nham foram";
}

?>
```

o código que antes era java foi implementado ao php.